# Activity starts where it shouldn't start

Tags: java, android, runnable

my class MainActivity starts the Activity "GameActivity" by user interaction (button). My class GameView is the view for my class GameActivity and has an implementation of the Runnable interface. Inside I've implemented a Handler as timer, that runs the trigger() method continuously. When `gameIsOver == true` the game stops and starts the GameOverActivity. Inside the GameOverActivity I've added a Button to commit the score. If you press the Button you get back to the MainView and you can start a new game.

Now to the problem: After I've played the game the GameOverActivity gets started, I commit the score and start a new Game or I end the Game and exit (not kill) the app.
In both ways, sometimes the GameOverActivity starts again and shows me that the Game is over. How could that be? Where is it called from? I guess the timer or the Runnable wasn't stopped correctly, but I really don't know what to do to prevent that problem...

PS: If the GameOverActivity gets started during the game, the game doesn't really end. If I press the back button on my phone, I'm just back in game.

*GameView.java*

```
private Handler timerHandler;
private boolean gameIsOver;
private long triggerTime, counter;

public void init() {
  gameIsOver = false;
  triggerTime = 1000;
  counter = 0;
  timerHandler = new Handler();

  Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (gameIsOver) {
        return;
      }
      long millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
      invalidate();

      if (millis > (triggerTime * counter)) {
        counter++;
        GameView.this.trigger();
      }

      timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 250);
    }
  };
  startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 250);
}
```

*inside the trigger() method:*

```
if (gameIsOver) {
  timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
  invalidate();

  Intent intent = new Intent(this.context, GameOverActivity.class);
  intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SCORE", score);
  // some more extras...
  ((Activity) this.context).startActivity(intent);
  ((Activity) this.context).finish();
}
```

[image: schematic view]

EDIT:

*GameActivity.java*

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

  private GameView game;
  private int level;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    level = intent.getExtras().getInt("EXTRA_LEVEL");

    game = (GameView) findViewById(R.id.game);
    game.setLevel(level);
  }
}
```

Comment: not sure about how it can help, but perhaps try `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)` instead of `removeCallbacks`?

Comment: Can you post the code from your GameActivity? The problem is most likely in there with how you are handling the lifecycle of the activity.

Comment: @cliffroot doesn't help.

Comment: where do you set `gameIsOver` to true?
it might happen that your `gameIsOver` is set to `true` when we already passed that condition in your `Runnable`. To quickly check it, you can add the same `if` right between your `postDelayed`

Comment: @cliffroot good thought, but the time between the `GameOverActivities` is to long and seems to be random. `gameIsOver = true` happens inside the `trigger()` method, so it should be finished before the `postDelayed` is called.